# How to change permission of Jenkins default directory from Read only?

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins through MSI in windows 2012. By default it's default directory is coming with Read only permission. Because of it, while i run the build, I am getting Access denied permission to workspace when it's trying to copy artifacts under release folder.

**Error:
 Copying file from "D:\foo.dll" to "bin\Debug\foo.dll".
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3540,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "D:\jenkins\workspace\foo.dll" to "bin\Debug\foo.dll". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\foo.dll' is denied. [D:\jenkins\workspace\foo.csproj]**

I tried to manually change permission. it worked for old projects. With new job, again it's changing permission to read only. I have installed it with administrator permission. Jenkins is running as a service. when I check through service it's running with Log on as "Local system account".

Can someone tell me how to fix permission issue with Jenkins?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to ensure that the windows service is running as a service account that has access to the internet (in particular nuget.org and / or maven central for the purposes of talking to those two site for dependency management purposes) and the service account is in the administrator group on the build machine.

A service account is one of the first things I ask for when I start a new project and sometimes, due to silly corporate security red tape, the hardest thing to get.

You could also look to write a batch file that calls [icacls.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.11).aspx) to recursively set permissions. [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.07.geekofalltrades.aspx) is also useful.

Be careful with this though as the runtime on such a job can grow exponentially as the number of files in JENKINS_HOME grows over time.